# Does a collection update trigger this.ready()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I couldn't find this info anywhere in the Meteor docs, but it seems `this.ready()` inside `this.autorun()` is always triggered after the collection (related with this publication) is modified. Is this true?

```
var h = this.subscribe('my-publication');

this.autorun(function() {
  if (h.ready()) {
    // Does this block run after a
    // collection add/update/remove? 
  } 
}
```

Comment: did you try it and see?

Comment: I tried and it does rerun after an update, but it's odd it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: Isn't the question ill posed? Presummably the code in the block depends on `h` or else the condition is hardly relevant. But if that is the case then autorun itself will trigger the rerun (`ready` is still true, as it was before).

Comment: @ChristianFritz, as this.ready() is a reactive var, I'm assuming autorun will rerun only when its value changes.

Comment: that depends on what else is inside the block. As soon as you use `MyPublication.find()` for instance, it will also rerun, assuming that's the name of the collection.

Comment: @ChristianFritz, so this is the point, if a find() fire the ready() flag (i.e. it'll change to false and back to true), where is this behavior documented?

Comment: no, the find triggers the autorun re-run directly. The ready state may never change.